# Hyperledger Fabric Calculate Hash / Signatures with SDK?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Is there a way existing for Fabric to calculate/recalculate signatures/hashs in using the SDK?

Comment: show what you have already done? some code

Answer (score 0):

It would be extremely difficult for an SDK or REcalculate. Without the help of the SHA3 SHAKE256 algorithm, SHA or MD5 cannot be decrypted *(encryption is still possible using [class hashing](https://guava.dev/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/hash/Hashing.html) - just don't use MD5 hashing to save passwords since it is not secure)* The SDK will have to know all the raw data to REcalculate the previous hash.

But the procedure to calculate the previous hash in hyperledger fabric would be:

1. Serialize the Block message to bytes using something similar to the protocol buffer library in hyperledger fabric.
2. Hash this serialized block message to 512 bits of output using something similar to the SHA3 SHAKE256 algorithm in hyperledger fabric.

Some websites do allow to decrypt the data but that is only because they have a database of all the public hash: [example website](https://md5decrypt.net/en/)

Using the above link, you can encrypt the data and store them on the website (or maybe create your database yourself) and then call the details using an API - but this can be done only if you already know the data corresponding to the hash.

Hope it was helpful.